# expect, anticipate , or look forword to life

Tags: word-choice

I want to express a sentence "expecting your life"

It's the feeling you eagerly want to see your lover and can't wait.
It's the feeling you get up happily because you know that something will make you happy today.
It' the feeling you live full of curiosity and great mood.

Which word should I choose?
expect, anticipate , or look forword to ?

Or is there anonther word or sentence get close to these feeling??
Thank you

Comment: Perhaps providing a sentence which encompasses the intended meaning but leaves a **blank** for the answer might be helpful?

Comment: I think you mean _forward_ instead of *_forword_. Looking forward to something is the only expression of those three that has a positive connotation, so I would go for that one. _Expect_ is utterly neutral, and _anticipate_ usually as well, except in an expression like "he was full of anticipation" — that is probably positive. But _anticipating life_ would mean to be well prepared for it, whether something positive or negative comes.

Comment: Are optimistic or upbeat too unimpressive?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest ***joie de vivre***:

> Exuberant enjoyment of life:
>   *they seem to be filled with joie de vivre*
>   *she had been gripped with a joie de vivre that hitherto had been completely missing from her life*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/joie-de-vivre)

There are quite a number of synonyms at that reference, as well.

Comment: +1 a similar sentiment is to *savor life*.

Answer (score 0):

Forms of the word *anticipate* work well with forms of the word *eager*; e.g.,

- eagerly anticipating
- eager anticipation